# No puedo realizar conexion PHP 5.6 a SQLSERVER

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Eh tratado de hacer funcionar `sqlserver` con `php` pero no eh tenido exito.
No me muestra en `phpinfo();` que tenga agrado el driver.

tengo esta configuración:

> System: Windows 10 Pro 1709 64 Bits
>   Compiler: MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012) 
>   Thread Safety: Enabled
>
> WampServer 3.0.6 64 Bits
>   Apache 2.4.23
>   PHP 5.6.25
>   SQL server managment studio 17.4

Cargue controladores 
me los muestra en PHP Extensions
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y los agregue al init
pero en phpinfo sigue sin mostramelo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No conosco mucho del tema, siempre utilize MYSQL, pero me pidieron conexión con una base de datos ya realizada en `SQL SERVER`.

Comment: Has intentado con PDO ODBC solo es necesario un driver SQL Server lo puedes encontrar aqui https://www.microsoft.com/es-cl/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Comment: Lo instale, pero tengo entendido que es para estos sistemas:
Sistemas operativos compatibles:
Windows 7; Windows 8; Windows Server 2008 R2; Windows Server 2012; Windows Server 2016; Windows Vista Service Pack 2

Comment: La versión 13 esta para windows 10

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Creo que [esta página te guiará mejor](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver) para descargar los controladores que necesitas. Te dice los sistemas operativos soportados, la versión de SQL Server soportada, y la versión de PHP soportada. Es que son tres cosas que hay que tener en cuenta. También ofrece ejemplos de código. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, al parecer era problema de windows 10, contaba con la version Pro 1703. cambie a windows 7 profesional y volvi a descargar los mismos paquetes de controladores y funciono correctamente.